# uncaught syntax error: document is not defined

Tags: javascript

I Don't understand why I keep getting this error-

> uncaught syntax error: document is not defined"

I am new to Stack overflow hopefully I am asking this correctly.

```
let  textArea = doucment.getElementById('text-area'),
     newGameButton = document.getElementById('new-game-button'),
     hitButton = document.getElementById('hit-button'),
     stayButton = document.getElementById('stay-button');


hitButton.style.display = 'none';
stayButton.style.display = 'none';
showStatus();


newGameButton.addEventListener('click', function () {  
    gameStarted = true;
    gameOver = false;
    playerWon = false;

    deck = createDeck();
    shuffleDeck(deck);
    dealerCards = [getNextCard(), getNextCard() ];
    playerCards = [getNextCard(), getNextCard() ];

    newGameButton.style.display = 'none';
    hitButton.style.display = 'inline';
    stayButton.style.display = 'inline';
    showStatus();
});
```

I added the `<script src="script.js"></script>` tag at the end of the body section of my HTML. i'm using VS Code editor, so maybe I messed up a setting or something?

Comment: In your first line of code, "document" is misspelled.

Comment: The typo would cause a reference but not a syntax error.

Comment: @Andreas seems you are correct `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: doucment is not defined",`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You misspelled "document" in the first line. You can create a variable to avoid typo errors.

```
var d = document;

let  textArea = d.getElementById('text-area'),
     newGameButton = d.getElementById('new-game-button'),
     hitButton = d.getElementById('hit-button'),
     stayButton = d.getElementById('stay-button');


hitButton.style.display = 'none';
stayButton.style.display = 'none';
showStatus();


newGameButton.addEventListener('click', function () {  
    gameStarted = true;
    gameOver = false;
    playerWon = false;

    deck = createDeck();
    shuffleDeck(deck);
    dealerCards = [getNextCard(), getNextCard() ];
    playerCards = [getNextCard(), getNextCard() ];

    newGameButton.style.display = 'none';
    hitButton.style.display = 'inline';
    stayButton.style.display = 'inline';
    showStatus();
});
```

Comment: Please do not answer typo type questions - also not a great idea to rename document - it is better kept as is for documentation reasons - lastly the misspelling gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: doucment is not defined`